# Laravel 5.1 unit test authenticate user

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

I want to test the user's authentication in my system, where I have some personalized routes for it.
Here my function to test it (in this case, I type wrong credentials for the user, but it is always successful:

```
public function testLoginFalse()
{
    $this->visit('/session/create')
        ->type('test@test.test', 'login')
        ->type('wrong-password', 'password')
        ->press('Login')
        ->seePageIs(route('pages.home'));
}
```

The problem the test in this case is always returning true, where it should be wrong !
I tried another way to test the login, but seems it is always working with wrong credentials (same problem):

```
public function testLoginFalse()
{
    $response = $this->route('POST', 'session.store', [
        'email' => 'test@test.test',
        'password' => 'wrong-password'
    ]);
    $this->assertEquals(302, $response->getStatusCode());
}
```

I took a look about the other questions with the same thema, but no one could fix my problem.
Is there an other way, or a better way, to test user's authentication?

**PS:** the user `test@test.test` already exists in the database.
I am using Laravel 5.1